# I am unable to automate the population of footers in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to automate the population of the footer of a google doc that I have with the values that a pop up dialogue gathers from the users when they open the document. The code that I am using can be seen below, however it only works with the footer of the first page, **when and only when I activate the option "Different first page"**. If I de-activate it (because I want the footer to be consistent within the whole document) nothing changes (not even the first page of the document) when I run the script.

The footer looks like this:

*Blablbla  /  ##value1##

Title: “##value2##” - blablabla*

The script to substitute value1 and value2 looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {

// Display a dialog box for each field you need information for.

  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

   var value1Response = ui.prompt('Enter the value1');

  var value2Response = ui.prompt('Enter the value2');
  var date = new Date();

  //Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('google document Id').makeCopy().getId();

  //Rename the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(value2Response.getResponseText() + date);  

  //Get the document footer as a variable
  var footer = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getFooter();


  footer.replaceText('##value1##', value1Response.getResponseText());
  footer.replaceText('##value2##', value2Response.getResponseText());

}
```

Comment: I created a Google Doc, inserted the footer for all pages with the "Different first page" option disabled, ran your script with 'google document Id' replaced by the template document Id and worked as expected replacing the input values for the footer in all pages.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will try with a new document from scratch just in case...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var value1Response = ui.prompt('Enter the value1');
  var value2Response = ui.prompt('Enter the value2');
  var value3Response = ui.prompt('Enter FileName');
  var date = new Date();
  var documentId = doc.getId();
  var footer = doc.getFooter();
  footer.replaceText('##value1##', value1Response.getResponseText());
  footer.replaceText('##value2##', value2Response.getResponseText());
  var doc=DocumentApp.openById("Doc Id");
  var footer=doc.getFooter();
  doc.setName(value3Response.getResponseText());
  footer.replaceText('##value1##', value1Response.getResponseText());
  footer.replaceText('##value2##', value2Response.getResponseText());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, sorry I am new to this and don't understand why the following part is repeated:

```var footer = doc.getFooter();
  footer.replaceText('##value1##', value1Response.getResponseText());
  footer.replaceText('##value2##', value2Response.getResponseText());